# C#/Windows: Play one audio file from speaker, and another audio file from the 'default audio device' (headphones/headset)?

Tags: c#, windows, audio, naudio

Is it possible to play one audio file from speaker, and another audio file from the 'default audio device' (headphones/headset), using any C# library e.g. NAudio.

I have some example code running in a C# console application, which does not seem to work:

```cs
using var mp3 = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

var dev = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);

Console.WriteLine(dev.Count); // - 2: Speaker + Headset

// basically play from all devices
foreach (var o in dev)
{
    var outSpeakerInit = new WasapiOut(o, AudioClientShareMode.Shared, true, 100);
    var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    outSpeakerInit.PlaybackStopped += (s, e) => ev.Set();
    outSpeakerInit.Init(mp3);
    outSpeakerInit.Play();
    ev.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/EnumerateOutputDevices.md

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - using WaveOut, DirectSoundOut and Wasapi API, nothing is played on the speaker. As for Asio, I don't have the driver (neither do most people). My code simply enumerates all audio devices for each of the valid naudio apis, then plays sound using all of them.

Comment: hm strange, just checking if you did call Init and Play on the audio device like described here https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlayAudioFileConsoleApp.md?

Comment: I've edited the question to include some code (this is for WASAPI, the 'new' api)

Comment: BTW to install ASIO on windows you probably need to install one of the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` packages from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 source https://think-async.com/Asio/

Comment: Nice, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on non-console apps .e.g WinForms. Maybe it's because of the presence of a windows event loop.

Comment: I don't think it needs a event loop but the thread you are calling the library from needs to  be available to schedule work. If you call `ev.WaitOne();` you probably spin look the current thread.You could go for async mechanisms maybe with `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` or just create a loop where you check for a boolean and then call `Thread.Sleep` with a small enough value that the thread can be used by other sources.

Comment: Even worse, turns out that it works in the first place - on my coworker's laptop, but just not on mine. I'm not sure if it's a driver issue of some sort.